# TLS / SSL3 using Winsock control

Tags: ssl, vb6, winsock, tls1.2

I have a VB6 Winsock control that communicates with a terminal (machine) using TCP/IP protocol. Connection's working fine, but it's closing when I try to send data to the machine.

What I need is that after connecting to the machine I have to send to the machine security infos using TLS or SSL3. Is there anyway to send to the machine the security information? I found a source code using VB.NET however I need it in VB6.

VB.NET code:

```
Dim oClient As TcpClient = Nothing
oClient = New TcpClient()
Dim oStream As SslStream = Nothing
oStram= New SslStream(oClient.GetStream(), False, AddressOfCertificateValidationCallBack)
oStream.AuthenticateAsClient("MEV", Nothing, SslProtocols.Tls, False)
```

Comment: No way to do that just in VB6 that I'm aware of, certainly not easily.  I've done this by making the SslStream connections and communications in a .net assembly and then calling that from VB6 using com interop.

Comment: Thank you so much.